# Set textArea of a JFrame to data from a file?

Tags: java, text, jtextarea

As the question states, I have a text file. Inside that text file is a few lines of text, and I want to populate my textArea with that data when the JFrame launches.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:/filepathchangedforStackOverflow");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    resultBox.read( br, null );
    br.close();

      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new RemoteDesktop().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
```

The error is on `resultBox.read( br, null );` as it is saying that `non-static variable resultBox cannot be referenced from a static context.`

I have looked everywhere and am not finding anything. It seems simple enough, I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Can share variable declaration of `resultBox`?

Comment: private javax.swing.JTextArea resultBox;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

class Main

{

```
static JFrame frame=new JFrame(); 
static JPanel panel=new JPanel();
private static void display(JFrame frame) throws IOException 
    {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null); 
        File file = null;
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)     
        file = chooser.getSelectedFile();    
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = in.readLine();
        while(line != null)
            {
                text.append(line + "\n");
                line = in.readLine();
            }
        panel.add(text);
        frame.add(panel);
    }
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    frame. setTitle("Simple example");
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    display(frame);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object of the class which contains the variable `resultBox`. Now access the variable `resultBox` using the reference variable of the object of the class.  For example if class name is `Test`, then:

`Test test=new Test( );`

`test.resultBox.read ( br, null );`

Could you please follow steps mentioned below and see the results:

Step 1: Create a text file whose path is : `"D:\\test.txt"`

Step 2: Replace your `public static void main(String args[])` with the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {     
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                RemoteDesktop rd=new RemoteDesktop();
                FileReader fr=null;
                try {
                    fr = new FileReader("D:\\test.txt");
                    rd.resultBox.read(fr, "Test");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    if(fr!=null){
                        try {
                            fr.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                rd.setSize(600,  400);
                rd.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                rd.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I haven't declared the resultBox anywhere. I simply dragged the Control onto the form using the Design view in NetBeans.

Comment: This fixed my error! Thanks (ps. still isn't displaying data, but that might be another issue)

Comment: Could you share name of the class which contains the variable `resultBox`?